# Refused to apply style “because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type” in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I move my code from **`"/var/www/html/demo"`** to **`"/var/www/html"`** after that **CSS** is not loading on my **Magento 2** admin panel. The frontend is working fine.

[image]

Comment: this happens when you have deleted the .htaccess inside your pub/static folder

Comment: please check, copy the .htaccess file from your old back then it should work

Comment: did you run static contents deploy?

Comment: thanks for the reply! i just followed the below steps :

download a fresh .htaccess file from the official repo here

https://github.com/magento/magento2

and replace or add in it pub/static   but no luck.

Comment: did it work? or not

Comment: [ec2-user@ip html]$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f                                                                                         -s standard
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to all                                                                                       ocate 2097152 bytes) in /var/www/html/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Parser.p                                                                                        hp on line 2726

Comment: try this `php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: same issue The script from “pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/requirejs/require.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.[Learn More] 316f440a42fd47b4eb2d2344f1b2e0be6bb1344d006ae597b5132103406d8ba0
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier[Learn More] require.js:1:27
The script from “/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.[Learn More] 316f440a42fd47b4eb2d2344f1b2e0be6bb1344d006ae597b5132103406d8ba0

Comment: @user999627 Did you change the application root in the apache or nginx virtual host config?